# Forcing apps on Marshmallow to use external sdcard (not internal /sdcard)

Tags: applications, external-sd

There seems to be quite a bit of discussion about this but no real resolution. I've been trying to find a way to mount directories on my external SD card onto the internal /sdcard directories to force apps that only can write data to /sdcard internally (that is, they have that directory path hardwired) to actually write to directories created on the external card (e.g. /storage/xxxx-xxxx/whatever). What a mess. I've tried symbolic links, battled the FUSE mounts, experimented with "mount -o bind" -- on and on. FolderMount claims to do such things, but bricks some phones. Adaptable storage doesn't solve this problem and creates new ones of its own in terms of control.

I can do the bind mounts -- and when I look at them with adb they appear to be correct. But the apps continue to write to the internal /sdcard dirs. I've also turned off SuperSu mount namespace separation in testing.

It's a shame that something that really should be so simple is such a PITA. Any new ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to put apps on SD card than you can try to set SD card as adoptable storage..? Edit: ooops I didn't read whole text, sorry

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I want key apps that write big files to /sdcard to *always* write to directories on the external card. I know of no way to ensure that with adaptable storage.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје you can delete your comment if necessary.

Comment: I'd prefer that it be left intact, so that my following clarification still makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps that can do that. Search for ***App2SD: All in one Tool*** (root version) on Google play. But you need to get root first in order for the app to work. Try Chainfire SuperSu, works fine on Marshmallow

Comment: Nope, they don't solve the problem at all. I'm familiar with both App2SD and Link2SD root versions. I use the latter. Link2SD in particular can move the app's local data -- in some cases (in many cases apps crash when you actually do this), but they don't move /sdcard. They do not provide any means I've found to solve the problem I'm discussing here, which is forcing apps to use external directories on the external SD rather than wired-in internal directories on the internal /sdcard.